# How to invert an existing regular expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, time

I have created a regex to validate time as follows : `([01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d`.

Matches TRUE : `08:00`, `09:00`, `9:00`, `13:00`, `23:59`.

Matches FALSE : `10.00`, `24:00`, `25:30`, `23:62`, `afdasdasd`, `ten`.

---

### QUESTION

How to invert a javascript regular expression to validate if **NOT** time?

***NOTE** - I have seen several ways to do this on stack but cannot seem to make them work for my expression because I do not understand how the invert expression should work.*

http://regexr.com?38ai1

---

### ANSWER

Simplest solution was to invert the javascript statement and NOT the regex itself.

`if (!(/^(([01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d)/.test(obj.value))`

Simply adding ! to create an if NOT statement.

Comment: Don't invert the regex, invert the `if` that checks it.

Comment: It seems simpler to negate the result of the validation rather than to create a regex for anything that is not a time.

Comment: I had considered this but was curious what peoples thoughts where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression is usually used for capturing some specific condition(s) - the more specific, the better the regex. What you're looking for is an extremely broad condition to match because just about everything wouldn't be considered "time" (a whitespace, a special character, an alphabet character, etc etc etc).

As suggested in the comments, for what you're trying to achieve, it makes much more sense to look for a time and then check (and negate) the result of that regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned in the comment, the better way is to negate the test rather then create a new regexp that matches any non-time.

However, if you really need the regexp, you could use negative lookahead to match the start of something that is not a time:

```
/^(?!([01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$)/
```

DEMO: http://regex101.com/r/bD3aG4

Note that i anchored the regexp (^ and $), which might not work with what you need it for.

Comment: In the site you've linked it seems that it doesn't match the statements that aren't time, like the OP asked...

Comment: @EladStern: how? Seems to work for me -- maybe it was edited?

Comment: It looks like the match is just the whitespace before the lines that aren't time, not the actual statement.

Comment: @EladStern Yes, it doesn't match the entire statement, just the start of the statement (not even a whitespace). If you need to match a statement, simply add a `.*` after the lookahead part, like [here](http://regex101.com/r/bD2wR6)